# How do I set isUndoable property of TextArea in javafx to true?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a simple text editor with JavaFx and when I call textArea.undo() as an even handler when a MenuItem is pressed, it doesn't work!. undo functionality only works when I press Ctrl+Z so i checked it out and noticed that the deafult isUndoable property is set to false! so how can I change that?

here's my code:

```
MenuItem undo = new MenuItem("Undo");
undo.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.Z, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
undo.setOnAction(e -> textArea.undo());
```

I also tried the following code:

```
textArea.isUndoable() = true;
```

but it turned out i can't do that!

Comment: After a quick search on the Internet, I think you have to define an `UndoableEditListener` to your TextArea. Take a look at that code, it's really short and should help you http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Undoredotextarea.htm

Comment: @Lutzi this is a JavaFX question, not a swing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property *cannot* be set, since it depends on an internal history of edits. You cannot modify this list directly. In your case the history just happens to have no more states for undoing

All you could do is try to make the history look the way you want it to using `replaceText` (or other editing methods using it) repeatedly, but even that groups changes and does not allow for full control of the edit history.

```
String wrongText = "Hello Worlt";
textArea.insertText(0, wrongText);
textArea.deleteText(wrongText.length()-1, wrongText.length());
textArea.insertText(wrongText.length()-1, "d");
// now there should be 2 changes to undo
```